# Can't unzip zip file in Terminal because of a single corrupted file

Tags: command-line, zip, unzip

I've got a large zip file that I am using Terminal to unzip, like so:

```
unzip /Volumes/9.25.17\ Backup/Documents.zip -d /Users/evan/Desktop/
```

When I try this, everything works fine until it tries to extract a particular mp4 file. It gets hung up on this one file every time:

```
inflating: /Users/evan/Desktop/Documents/Creativity/Rotblatt copy.mp4  error:  zipfile read error
```

I don't really care about this file - is there any way to tell terminal to ignore it while unzipping?

Comment: Try with the `-x "copy.mp4"`

Comment: I've tried using -x followed by just about every possible iteration of the filename but it still tries to read it

Comment: Try `unzip /Volumes/9.25.17\ Backup/Documents.zip -x "copy.mp4" -d /Users/evan/Desktop/`

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. Does more of the file path need to be included?

Comment: yes it has to be included addind an answer now

Comment: Can you append the output of `uname -a` to your question?

Answer (score 4):

It's not that the file "copy.mp4" is corrupted, it is that the zip file itself has some damage.

You can attempt to fix the zip file:

`zip -F /Volumes/9.25.17\ Backup/Documents.zip --out newfile.zip`

and then attempt to extract the files from `newfile.zip`.  If this does not work, you can attempt a more comprehensive fix:

`zip -FF /Volumes/9.25.17\ Backup/Documents.zip --out newfile.zip`

Comment: -F doesn't work.

-FF gives: zip I/O error: Read-only file system

Comment: @EvanOlawsky You will need to run the command in a file system to which you have write permissions...  I updated the command (I forgot the --out modifier)

Comment: Yes, I included the --out modifier. What do you mean about a file system where I have write permissions?

Comment: The "I/O error: Read-only file system" would seem to indicate that you do not have write permissions

Comment: How do I change the permissions? All of this is on my personal laptop.

Comment: I don't know what directory you are working in, but my guess would be that you are working in `/Volumes/9.25.17\ Backup`, and that this might be a directory created by a backup routine of some sort.  *I* would try to create the newfile.zip in my home directory by `zip -FF /Volumes/9.25.17\ Backup/Documents.zip --out ~/newfile.zip`, and then attempt to unzip the file from there.

Comment: Alas, I'm still getting the same error message:
    Fix archive (-FF) - salvage what can
    zip I/O error: Read-only file system
    zip error: Temporary file failure (/Volumes/9.25.17 Backup/ziEOU74V)

Comment: Can you copy the entire zip file to your home directory and perform the operation from there?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem due to power failure when recording some data and directly passing it to zip. The zip file was missing the ending.
`zip -F` or `zip -FF` did not solve the problem. Finally I found solution, that allowed to save most of the file:

`jar xvf Document.zip`

The last part of corrupted file was still lost, but it was good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the absolute path to the file with:

   ```
   unzip -l /Volumes/9.25.17\ Backup/Documents.zip | grep copy.mp4
   ```
2. Then do:

   ```
   unzip /Volumes/9.25.17\ Backup/Documents.zip -x "/path/to/file/from/step/1/copy.mp4" -d /Users/evan/Desktop/
   ```

Comment: This works (the process ignores the file I want it to), but it turns out there are more files that it gets hung up on too.

Comment: Sounds as if the problem is a corrupt zip file.

Comment: @EvanOlawsky then it appears that it didn't download completely